# Stuck to figure out how to access a certain field to update

Tags: json, meteor

I have this JSON FILE

```
{
    "_id": "GgCRguT8Ky8e4zxqF",
    "services": {
    "emails": [
        {
            "address": "Abunae@naa.com",
            "verified": false,
            "verifiedMail": "Toto@hotmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "profile": {
        "name": "Janis"
    },
    "pushIds": []
}
```

I want to update my verifiedMail field but couldn't figure out how to do it in Meteor, it's always returning me an error

```
  let VerifiedEmail = "Exemple1"
   await Meteor.users.update({ _id: user._id }, { $set: { 'emails.verifiedEmail': emailRefactor} }, { upsert: true })
```

Couldn't figure out how to access the emails.verifiedEmail field

Tried this exemlpe  worked like a charm

```
let VerifiedEmail = "Exemple1"
   await Meteor.users.update({ _id: user._id }, { $set: { 'profile.name': emailRefactor} }, { upsert: true })
```

but couldn't figure out how to access emails.verifiedEmail .

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Emails is an array, while profile is an object. You have to access the first object of the email array instead

Comment: could you please tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familliar with Meteor

Comment: You can also just remove the brackets if you only have 1 e-mail object, if you are able to change the json ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

This updates the exact email address from emails

```
Meteor.users.update({
            "emails.address": emailRefactor
        }, {
            $set: {
                "emails.$.verified": true
            }
        });
```

Or update the first element

```
Meteor.users.update({
                 _id: user._id,
                "emails.address": emailRefactor
            }, {
                $set: {
                    "emails.0.verified": true
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not updating the field and not throwing any error :/ couldn't figure out where the problem is comming

Comment: Maybe there's no one with emailRefactor in database. Check what update returns.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set *verifiedEmail* while the actual field is *verifiedMail*.